# Entering a comma delimited string into an INT column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to add a comma delimited string into a column in my table set to INT.
I used it to reference a Category ID but now I'd like the possibility to add more than just 1 category.

Thinking I could accomplish this by entering a string like: 1,2,3 instead of just 1 but i'm getting errors that the changed value in this cell was not recognized as valid.

Does this mean I need to change that column to VARCHAR instead of INT?

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a many to many relation ship. The right way to deal with this is NOT by stuffing a bunch on values into a single cell. This is a nightmare. The data you are trying to model is called an Associative Entity. The way you deal with this is called a bridge table. What that means if you create a third table with two columns (ProductID and CategoryID). Then you add a row to this table for each category for each product.

Comment: Thank you Sean i'm understanding a bit better now. I'll look up Associative Entries to understand better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this means that you should set up proper tables to support a 1-many relationship.  That is, you want a separate *table*, not a bogus data representation in a varchar column.

Why?  Well, SQL has this great data structure for lists, called a *table*.  In addition:

- Numbers should be stored in native format, not a string.
- SQL has (relatively) poor functions for manipulating strings.
- Operations on the column will not take advantage of indexes.
- If the numbers represent ids in another table, you cannot declare proper foreign key references.

Comment: can you give me an example please.

Comment: I have a separate table with my categories listed and a unique ID. I'm using the ID to reference which rows on my primary table match the categories on my secondary table.

Comment: @AlexP . . . You should ask another question with sample data and describe what you want to know about setting up a proper junction table.

Comment: Sean Lange's comment has helped me find what I need to lookup. I'm reading about many-to-many relationships now. I will post a new question once I have some code to display.

Thank you